# Slow join on Inserted/Deleted trigger tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

We have a trigger that creates audit records for a table and joins the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to see if any columns have changed.  The join has been working well for small sets, but now I'm updating about 1 million rows and it doesn't finish in days.  I tried updating a select number of rows with different orders of magnitude and it's obvious this is exponential, which would make sense if the `inserted`/`deleted` tables are being scanned to do the join.

I tried creating an index but get the error:
`Cannot find the object "inserted" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

Is there any way to make this any faster?

Comment: I just thought of selecting each of these into new temp tables, after which I should be able to create indexes.  However, I'm also concerned on the performance for individual records and this seems overkill for those.

Comment: @Martin - It's 2005 and I just updated the tag to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting into temporary tables indexed on the joining columns could well improve things as `inserted` and `deleted` are not indexed.

You can check `@@ROWCOUNT` inside the trigger so you only perform this logic above some threshold number of rows though on SQL Server 2008 this might overstate the number somewhat if the trigger was fired as the result of a `MERGE` statement (It will return the total number of rows affected by all `MERGE` actions not just the one relevant to that specific trigger).

In that case you can just do something like `SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM INSERTED) T` to see if the threshold is met.

**Addition**

One other possibility you could experiment with is simply bypassing the trigger for these large updates. You could use `SET CONTEXT_INFO` to set a flag and check the value of this inside the trigger. You could then use `OUTPUT inserted.*, deleted.*` to get the "before" and "after" values for a row without needing to `JOIN` at all.

```
DECLARE @TriggerFlag varbinary(128)
SET @TriggerFlag = CAST('Disabled' AS varbinary(128)) 

SET CONTEXT_INFO @TriggerFlag

UPDATE YourTable
SET Bar = 'X'
OUTPUT inserted.*, deleted.* INTO @T

/*Reset the flag*/
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x
```

Comment: Great point on setting a threshold.  That could make the trigger quite complicated, but I suppose there are tradeoffs to anything.  I'm still baffled by one thing: we have another database that is almost identical and it's not experiencing this slowdown.  The tables, triggers and indexes appear to be identical, though I haven't done a detailed compare yet.